# Oracle sql query sum data every month

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say i have selected data from oktober until desember like this

[image]

i want to get sum of buying customer in every months (okt-des)
The result i want is like table below

[image]

i already know how to get last day of months 
but i don't have idea query in SQL to get result like i need

Comment: Don't say "plsql" when you (clearly) don't know what it means, just because you heard of it. I edited your post and removed the `plsql` tag. Then: Do you just have data for October to December 2017, or possibly for other dates too? And, do you just need the output for those specific months (October to December 2017)?

Comment: @mathguy yeah i have data for other date, but i want just need output from spesific months (okt - des 2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this - if you just need the data for those three months - is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select   name,
         sum(case when dt >= date '2017-10-01' and dt < date '2017-11-01'
                  then buying end) as oktober,
         sum(case when dt >= date '2017-11-01' and dt < date '2017-12-01'
                  then buying end) as november,
         sum(case when dt >= date '2017-12-01' and dt < date '2018-01-01'
                  then buying end) as desember
from     YOUR_TABLE
where    dt >= date '2017-10-01' and dt < date '2018-01-01'
group by name
;
```

Note that `date` is an Oracle keyword which should not be used as a column name; I changed it to `dt`.  `YOUR_TABLE` should be your actual table name.

Comment: How would this be done to dynamically include any date? For example if the dates range is from 01-01-2017 to 12-31-2019. what happens if future dates like 10-15-2999 and 10-31-2999 were to be added to the table?

Comment: @swagless_monk - queries where the number of columns is not known at compile time, but only at execution, are much more difficult. This is the whole topic of "dynamic SQL" - an advanced topic, most often the pivoting is done in reporting software (not in the query itself) - and presenting data that way is generally a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 DESC TABLE_NAME
        NAME    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
        BUYING  NUMBER
        BUYING_DATE DATE

    select * from
    (
    select name,buying,RTRIM(to_char(buying_Date,'Month')) dd
    from
    TABLE_NAME
    )
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(buying)
    for dd IN ('October','November','December')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Should each month be a separate column?If not, then you can use window functions.

*ORDER BY Name* - will show the total amount for the month for each day.

*DISTINCT* - will remove duplicate lines

*last_day(Date)* - Will return the last day of the month

```
WITH data AS(
    SELECT Name,Buying,Date 
    FROM 'your_table'
    WHERE Data between 'start_date' and 'end_date')

SELECT DISTINCT Name,last_day(Date) as DATE,
(SUM(Buying) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(Date,'MONTH'),Name ORDER BY Name) as MONTH_BUYING FROM data
```

As written above `date` is an Oracle keyword which should not be used as a column name